# Obtaining opencv UMat shape in python

Tags: python, opencv, opencl, gpu

I'm working on a project involving calculations on GPU in openCV.

Is there a direct way to obtain shape (number of cols and rows) of UMat array without converting it first to numpy object in Python?

Comment: Small update: I've asked similar question on OpenCV forum. Apparently there is no easy way to get those values. In my case I found a half-solution, as every UMat matrix is first numpy matrix (before transfer to GPU). So at this moment we have access to shape and we have to remember it in separate variable for further calculations. This helps me, but there are some cases when it is not possible to use this solution.

Answer (score 3):

Actually there's not an easy way to do that :-(

You can:

A)Store shape before upload image to GPU (like you do, best way)

B)Download the image from GPU and get its `shape` using something like this (BAD WAY, but Works):

```
    shape = yourUMat.get().shape
```